# IF statement to turn positive values into negative values in Excel

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I have a dataset of lat/lon coordinates in Excel, but some of the coordinates were improperly entered. What would be the Excel code to change a positive coordinate to a negative one (and leave negative values as they are)?

```
latitude    longitude
25.66632    -80.26313
25.65948    80.26483
25.64070    -80.27083
25.63548    -80.27487
25.63320    80.27678
25.63137    -80.27763
```

Comment: You want `-|value|` which can be done with `-ABS(value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If longitude data is in column C (from C2 onwards, say) - then you can deploy a couple of synonymous techniques - depending upon your preference:

1. `=if(C2>0,-C2,C2)` : perhaps most intuitive
2. `=-abs(C2)` : parsimonious, kudos to Jadefalke (26/01/22 - commentary)

Array functions exist for these too - i.e. for a column of data C2:C10, you can enter (once) in the corresponding leading (top) cell =-abs(C2:C10).  see [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/07/08/excel-dynamic-arrays-functions-formulas/) for details RE: Office 365 compatible vs. prior versions of Excel.